# The 'Locally Ringed' condition in the definition of a scheme.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, ringed-spaces

Is the 'Locally Ringed' condition in the definition of a Scheme redundant? My question is, if it admits a cover by Affine Schemes, does it follow that the Ringed space is Locally Ringed?

More generally, if a Ringed Space $(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$ admits a cover $\{U_i\}$ such that each $(U_i,{\mathscr{O}_{X}}_{|U_i})$ is Locally Ringed, is $(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$ itself Locally Ringed?

Comment: I think you're right.

Comment: Have you got a proof?

Comment: Take any $x\in X$ and fix $U_i$ such that $x\in U_i$. Then the stalk of $\mathcal O_X$ at $x$ is the same as the stalk of its restriction ${\mathscr{O}_{X}}_{|U_i}$ to $U_i$, hence it is a local ring.

Comment: I also agree. I think the literature phrases the definition as it does to highlight that a scheme is indeed a locally ringed space, which is often important. Introducing it as a ringed space for the sake of minimalism might be confusing in a larger number of cases compared to doing it this way =).

Comment: It's important that a morphism of schemes is a morphism in the category of locally ringed spaces, not in the category of ringed spaces.

Comment: I get it now, thanks.